# Is it possible to calculate the total resistance of this circuit with series and parallel analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

If I have a circuit like the one below, is it possible to determine the total resistance with the usual series and parallel analysis? I have been staring at it for a while and cannot see how I might do it because of the resistors on the left and the right. Hints would be appreciated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuQlM6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I am not trying to be a smart alec. But there are no resistance values in the circuit. In fact, the rectangles have to be assumed to be resistors. Should we assume that all resistors have the same value, which we can call "R" and then solve from there?

Comment: I think because the circuit is very symmetric, there is probably a trick you can use to analyze it.

Comment: the question that you posted does not ask what is the equivalent resistance. .... it asks if the resistance can be solved by a particular method. .... it makes no difference what the resistor values are .... the answer would be either yes or no.

Comment: @mkeith I left the values blank because I want to know how to go about finding the equivalent resistance for a circuit like this in general. If I gave specific values people might think it was a homework question or something

Comment: That makes sense. I will just tell you that I am way too impatient to analyze a circuit like that. I would enter it into a simulator and let the simulator figure out what the total load on the supply is. I will let others actually answer your question, but at first glance, I agree with Elliot Alderson. Nothing is in series or parallel (except the supply is in series with one of the resistors). So some other form of analysis is required.

Comment: It might be helpful to at least give each resistor a reference designator. It is hard to discuss a circuit which does not have reference designators.

Comment: wye to delta transformation on some of the three-resistor junctions will yield triangles, and parallel resistors that can then be simplified.

Answer (score 3):

If by "parallel and series analysis" you mean combining resistors in series and parallel until you have a single resistor then no, you can't use that kind of analysis because there aren't any resistors in series or parallel to combine. I would be inclined to use node voltage analysis myself.

However, other people might prefer other methods of analysis, such as source transformation or delta-wye transformation. I usually just go for a nodal analysis because it is a general technique and I know it will work.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that then. Also isn't delta-wye only useful when the resistors are in a triangle? I thought about trying that but here there are only quadrilaterals

Comment: wye to delta transformation on some of the three-resistor junctions will yield triangles, and parallel resistors that can then be simplified.